# JavaScript function involving XMLHttpRequest fails unless I include an alert() statement

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, alert

I have a JavaScript function used by the onblur event of a textbox. The textbox captures an email address

```
function strEmailUnique(strEmail, intClientID) {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET", 'AJAX_retrieval.php?strEmail=' + strEmail + '&intClientID=' + intClientID, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  return xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

The AJAX call returns the name of the person with that email if the email exists, otherwise it returns an empty string.

However, it doesn't work. At least, not until I insert this line

```
alert('xmlhttp.responseText: ' + xmlhttp.responseText);
```

before the return statement. I have no idea why this works - and I need to know, because obviously I don't want the alert in the live code.

When I say "it works", the actual alert when it happens indicates an empty response, but the subsequent behaviour indicates that a non-empty value is returned by the function. This too is a mystery.

I have tried accessing the response before returning it (which I figured is what the alert() is doing)

```
var strResponse = xmlhttp.responseText;
return strResponse;
```

and I also thought that it might be a timing/synchronisation issue so I tried inserting this

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
  if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > 3000){
    break;
  }
}
```

from [JavaScript sleep/wait before continuing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873323/javascript-sleep-wait-before-continuing) before the return, but to no avail.

My onblur event code (which I don't think is relevant) is

```
var strDB_outcome = strEmailUnique(document.getElementById('email').value, -1); if (strDB_outcome != '') alert('The email address ' + document.getElementById('email').value + ' is already registered to ' + strDB_outcome); "
```

and the AJAX target does this

```
  echo fetch_datum($conn, "SELECT IFNULL((SELECT REPLACE(CONCAT(LEFT(strForenames, 1), '_', strSurname), ' ', '') FROM $tblClients WHERE LOWER(strEmail) = LOWER('{$_GET['strEmail']}') AND intClientID <> {$_GET['intClientID']} LIMIT 1), '')");
```

which again I don't think is relevant - this stuff does what I expect as long as the alert() is included in the JS function. What can I do instead of the alert() statement?

The following SO questions all seem to involve more complex scenarios

[JavaScript won't work unless I use alert()!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524000/javascript-wont-work-unless-i-use-alert)

[Javascript ignores part of code unless I put an "alert" before it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461854/javascript-ignores-part-of-code-unless-i-put-an-alert-before-it)

[Form fields not populated from AJAX unless I include an alert in the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766507/form-fields-not-populated-from-ajax-unless-i-include-an-alert-in-the-code)

or very specific fixes.

Comment: You need a "succes" function that calls the function that processes the data. You cannot return data from your function unless you make the call synchronous - ruining the whole point - more here [MDN Ajax getting started](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started#Step_3_–_A_Simple_Example)

Comment: mplungjan, I'd hardly call it a "duplicate" - but thanks for pointing me in the direction of the answer, I appear to have it working by adding an onload callback. I think it might be helpful to someone if I was able to post the working code, though.

Comment: The second answer is using the exact same code you are: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16825593/295783 - the duplicate link is answering any question about async for anyone else needing this. So yes it is a duplicate